# postgresql loop for maximum cumulative rainfall in a week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a data rainfall (one data for every hour) from 1994 to 2005. I want to calculate maximum cumulative for a week by using sql. From million of data, I have to select data of the first week (168 hrs), then I have to sum the data from 1-24 hrs, 2 to 25 hrs and etc till 168, and select the maximum of this 145 summation to be the data of the maximum cumulative rainfall for first week.
Then return to table and continue for the next 168 hrs.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maxcrain() RETURNS numeric AS $BODY$
declare a int;
declare b int;
declare c int;
declare temp int;
begin
    while id <= b + 145 loop
begin

    while id <= a + 24 loop
begin

    if rain > 0 then

        c := 0;
        c = c + rain
        id = id + 1


    else
        id = id + 1
        continue
end

        a = a + 1

        id = a

        if (c > temp)
        temp = c
        update maxcrain = temp
end loop

        b = id + 23
end loop;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: don't use `=` for assignment. It only works because of historic reasons and will be removed in a future version. Always make sure you use `:=` as the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

Do this using window functions!

```
select week, max(hr24value)
from (select rf.*,
             floor(rf.hour/168) as week,
             sum(rf.value) over (partition by week
                                 order by hour
                                 rows between 23 preceding and current row
                                ) as hr24value
      from rainfall rf
     ) rf
group by week;
```

If your version of Postgres doesn't support that `rows` clause, then use a cumulative sum and `lag()`:

```
select week, max(hr24value)
from (select rf.*,
             (cumvalue - lag(cumvalue) over (partition by week order by hour)
             ) as hr24value
      from (select rf.*,
                   floor(rf.hour/168) as week,
                   sum(rf.value) over (partition by floor(rf.hour/168) 
                                       order by hour
                                      ) as cumvalue
            from rainfall rf
           ) rf
     ) rf
group by week;
```

Comment: err, I think u misunderstand what I want. I'm finding the maximum cumulative rain after sum of the 1st hr to 24th hr,2nd hr to 25th hr etc till 168, and among the 145 data calculate for the first week, only find the maximum value of it. thanks yea~~

Comment: @user3860940 . . . I understood that.  This is what the query should be doing.